# VBA: Format cell on #VALUE Error

Tags: error-handling, excel, excel-formula, vba

I've created a function that searches a specific value on a range and returns adjacent characteristics.

```
Function Busca(valor As String)
    Dim bus(0 To 1)
    bus(0) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A10").Find(valor, LookAt:=xlWhole). _
        Offset(0, 1)
    bus(1) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A10").Find(valor, LookAt:=xlWhole). _
        Offset(0, 2)
    Busca = bus
End Function
```

If there is no match for `valor` in `A1:A10`, the function returns `{#VALUE,#VALUE}`, wich is ok, but I'd like to return instead something like `{"No match", ""}`, with the "No match" cell in a given color. I've tried data validation, error handling and `If` `Then` with `ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex`to no avail. Also, if the error is corrected, I'd like the cell to go back to transparent.

I guess an event handler could do the trick, but I'm new at VBA and there are still a lot of things that I don't understand.

**EDIT**

As suggested, to be clear:

How do I make the output cell(s) to change color if no match is found, and to have no color if a match is found (in VBA)?

Comment: Your function as shown doesn't return anything...  Have you considered just using a worksheet formula like VLOOKUP() ?  Functions (when called from a worksheet) can't change the sheet: they can only return values to the calling cells.  If you need to add color then you could use Conditional Formatting.

Comment: I've corrected the formula. I didn't know that functions can't change the sheet. As Conditional Formatting, I'm not sure if it's more convenient to add the functionality as a Sub. I want the a regular user not to be able to change things, but don't want to protect the workspace with a pw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a completely rewritten answer in the light of new information from the questioner.

If I understand correctly, you wish to create a Custom Function that will change the colour of a cell.  The following text from Microsoft's Help on custom functions says you cannot:

> The number of VBA keywords you can use in custom functions is smaller
>   than the number you can use in macros. Custom functions are not
>   allowed to do anything other than return a value to a formula in a
>   worksheet or to an expression used in another VBA macro or function.
>   For example, custom functions cannot resize windows, edit a formula in
>   a cell, or change the font, color, or pattern options for the text in
>   a cell. If you include "action" code of this kind in a function
>   procedure, the function returns the #VALUE! error.

I know of two alternatives that might meet your requirements.  A third alternative was added later after a flash of inspiration.

**Alternative 1: Offer a drop down list of the permitted values**

Position the cursor to a cell which is to have restricted values.  Select Data from the toolbar then Validation.  A Data Validation form is displayed.

Select the Settings tab if not already selected.  Click the box under "Allow:" and select List.  In the Source box enter: "=$A$1:$A$10". (The "=" is required. The $s are important if you want to be able to create copies of this cell.)  Click OK.

When the user positions the cursor to that cell they can either enter a permitted value or can select a permitted value from the list.  An attempt to enter any other value will result in an error message.  The other tabs within the Data Validation form allow you to enter a help message and your own error message.

Because of the $s in the source box, you can copy the original cell and its validation to other cells.

**Alternative 2: Conditional formatting**

If the permitted values are a range, conditional formatting will meet your requirements.  For example suppose the permitted range is 10 to 20.

Select Format from the toolbar then Conditional Formatting.

Boxes for condition 1 are displayed.  "Between" is already displayed.  In the boxes to the right enter 10 and 20.

Click Add to display boxes for condition 2.  Replace Between" by "Less than".  In the next box enter 10.  Click Format.  Click Colour.  Select Red.  Click OK.

Click Add to display boxes for condition 3.  Replace Between" by "Greater than".  In the next box enter 20.  Click Format.  Click Colour.  Select Red.  Click OK.

Click OK to accept the conditional formatting.

The user can enter anything they like into the cell but it will be red unless it is between 10 and 20.

You can create as many copies of the formatted cell as you wish.

**Worksheet change event**

I should have thought of events before.  I believe this does exactly what you want.

Within the VBA Editor, the Project Explorer is normally visible on the left of the screen.  If it is not, Click `Ctrl+R`.

Right click the line for the worksheet within which selected values are to be controlled.  Click `View Code`.

The code area will be headed Worksheet but will otherwise be blank.  You can place various routines in this area but the relevant routines are the worksheet event routines.  These are routines that will be called whenever an event such as worksheet activated or deactivated occurs.  The event you want is Change which is called whenever the user changes a cell.  The attraction of this routine is that it can do anything you want.

Copy and Paste the Worksheet_Change routine below into the worksheet code area.

Its parameter is the address of the cell that the user has changed.

TgtRngList is set to a list of the ranges you wish to patrol.  I have set this to C1:C1000, F1:F1000 and A1.  You will have to change this to the ranges you want to patrol.

OKValueList is set to a list of the permitted values for the patrolled ranges.  They could be in a sheet somewhere but I think it is easier to define them here.  Change the list to whatever you want.

The code checks for the changed cell being in one of the patrolled area.  If it is, it is checked to have a permitted value.  The result of that check causes the cell to be set to black or red.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal ChangedCell As Range)

  ' This routine is called whenever the user changes a cell.
  ' It is not called if a cell is changed by Calculate

  Dim ColChanged As Integer
  Dim InxOV As Integer
  Dim InxTR As Integer
  Dim OKValueList() As Variant
  Dim Patrolled As Boolean
  Dim RowChanged As Integer
  Dim TgtColLeft As Integer
  Dim TgtColRight As Integer
  Dim TgtRngPartList() As String
  Dim TgtRngList() As Variant
  Dim TgtRngPart As String
  Dim TgtRowBottom As Integer
  Dim TgtRowTop As Integer
  Dim ValueChanged As String
  Dim ValueOK As Boolean

  ' Fill TgtRngList withe ranges that are to be patrolled by this routine
  TgtRngList = Array("C1:C1000", "F1:F1000", "A1")

  ' Fill OKValueList with the permitted values for these cells.
  OKValueList = Array("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", _
                      "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10")

  ColChanged = ChangedCell.Column
  RowChanged = ChangedCell.Row

  Patrolled = False
  For InxTR = LBound(TgtRngList) To UBound(TgtRngList)
    TgtRngPartList = Split(TgtRngList(InxTR), ":")
    ' Decode top left of range
    TgtRngPart = TgtRngPartList(LBound(TgtRngPartList))
    TgtRowTop = Range(TgtRngPart).Row
    TgtColLeft = Range(TgtRngPart).Column
    If LBound(TgtRngPartList) = UBound(TgtRngPartList) Then
      ' There is no colon so single cell range
      TgtRowBottom = TgtRowTop
      TgtColRight = TgtColLeft
    Else
      TgtRngPart = TgtRngPartList(UBound(TgtRngPartList))
      TgtRowBottom = Range(TgtRngPart).Row
      TgtColRight = Range(TgtRngPart).Column
    End If
    If RowChanged >= TgtRowTop And RowChanged <= TgtRowBottom And _
       ColChanged >= TgtColLeft And ColChanged <= TgtColRight Then
      ' This is a patrolled cell
      Patrolled = True
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
  If Patrolled Then
    With ActiveSheet
      ValueChanged = .Cells(RowChanged, ColChanged).Value
      ' Check value against permitted list
      ValueOK = False
      For InxOV = LBound(OKValueList) To UBound(OKValueList)
        If ValueChanged = OKValueList(InxOV) Then
          ValueOK = True
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
      If ValueOK Then
        ' Set cell black
        .Cells(RowChanged, ColChanged).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
      Else
        ' Set cell red
        .Cells(RowChanged, ColChanged).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      End If
    End With
  End If

End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Indeed I was missing a parenthesis in the code. See above comment. The objective is to compare an input, in this case, `valor`, to a range, lets say `A1:A10`. If a match is found in say, `A3`, the function returns the values of `B3:C3`. If no match is found, I want the output cell to change color. This is the real issue, the change color part, not the find part (as badly coded as it might be). Sorry for not including the `If` `Then` part.

Comment: The info on functions was very helpfull. Drop downs aren't a good solution, but conditional formatting might. If `#VALUE` is returned, I could do error-handling to asign some wierd value, like 10,000,000, and then use conditional formatting as you say. I still would prefer a VBA solution, wich means creating a macro triggered by my function, as stated in your answer.

Comment: I have had an inspiration.  See third alternative in my answer.

Comment: I've been very occupied with no time to check your inspiration, but as soon as possible I will. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Sorry for delay. Between the holidays and other projects, I wasn't able to review your code. It's seems very interesting the way you propose to patrol cells. I'm accepting it as answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you are going with offset appended to xlWhole, which refers to whether or not to check the whole cell. Here are some notes, you will see that find returns an object:

```
Function Busca(valor As String)
''http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195730(v=office.11).aspx
Dim bus(0 To 1)
With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A10")
    Set c = .Find(valor, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        bus(0) = c.Address

        Set c = .FindNext(c)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            bus(1) = c.Address
        Else
            bus(1) = "None"
        End If
    Else
        bus(0) = "None"
    End If
End With
Debug.Print bus(0), bus(1)
Busca = bus
End Function
```

Comment: Aww, this is embarrassing. There is a missing parenthesis in the code. It should read `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A10").Find(valor, LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 1)`. I've corrected it now. The point is to retrieve the info on the cell right to the match and the info two cells right of the match.

Comment: @Manuel You say "if no match is found, the output cell changes colour". What is the output cell? I am afraid you are still not being clear. Do You mean find something, if the cell to the right matches, fine, if not, change the colour of the cell to the right?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. The output cell would be the one where the function has been entered. As in the comment I put in @TonyDallimore's answer, suppose I enter the function in cells `F10:F11`, I want `F10` to change colour if no match is found.

Comment: @Manuel Have you got anything against buttons?