# VBA to prevent a change event from triggering if another change event triggers

Tags: excel, events, vba

this one may be impossible to solve in VBA but I'd like to see what you experts have to say about it.

I have a textbox on a userform that triggers a macro within a TextBox1_Change() type of sub.

If the user types "ABC" in the textbox, the macro gets triggered 3 times: once for "A", once for "AB" and once for "ABC". This macro is actually kind of heavy, so I would like it to run only when the user is actually done typing, and not inbetween single key strokes.

I know I can make the user "press enter" or whatever and only then run the macro, but this is not what I'm looking for. I want him to type freely and see the results of his typing dynamically show up, with no other type of interaction required.

So, I came up with the idea of making the change event wait and see if another change event gets triggered within, say, 1 second from the first. If that happens, the first change event aborts.

Now this would work, and I think I would know how to code it, except that I don't know how to give the user the power to keep typing even when the first change event is running.

What I mean is that when the first macro runs, it "freezes" everything. Waiting to see if another change event triggers will therefore not work, as nothing is going to trigger until the first macro is done running.

Do you guys see my problem here? How would you go about this? Any chance I can achieve the results I'd like?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks guys!

Comment: why not use `TextBox1_AfterUpdate` which will fire when the textbox loses focus?

Comment: @brettdj Thanks for your reply, this is an option but I will put it in the "make the user press enter or whatever" category. It needs the textbox to lose focus, i.e. the user to interact with the sheet in some way other than typing. And I don't want that. :) By using the change event, my textbox looks much like the google search bar, where you input some text and you're dynamically shown a list of possibilities as you type. That's ultimately what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: Have you looked at `DoEvents`?

Comment: I can conceive of a horrible, anything but Google-like hack using `Application.OnTime` and a global flag to record whether an `OnTime` has already been set to fire... You should ask yourself: do the ends justify the means?

Comment: @creamyegg: `DoEvents` will flush the event queue. This is the opposite of what the OP is asking, as far as I can tell. The OP is looking to *clear* everything from the event queue except the last in queue, so to speak.

Comment: @creamyegg almost there, something like `Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim x As Variant
   x = Timer()
   Do While x + 1 > Timer()
       DoEvents
   Loop
    Call TextBox1Change
End Sub` gives the user one more second to type in some extra stuff before firing the macro. Now I only need to add a line that tells the system to abort the first macro if another change_event is triggered within that time window. Any clue on how to do that?

Comment: @Bruder: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9378989/119775) may inspire you. It's a different problem, but the approach could be rather similar, except using `OnTime` instead of `OnKey`.

Comment: Also, Microsoft KB says: Make sure the procedure that has given up control with DoEvents is not executed again from a different part of your code before the first DoEvents call returns; this can cause unpredictable results. Isn't this exactly what I'm doing here? What does "unpredictable" results mean?

Comment: I wouldn't do like you suggest in your comment above (Do ... Loop). This will recursively call the same procedure over and over, and you could run into a [stack overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow)!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Hmm, I tried messing around with it a bit but I can't seem to get it right. First, how else am I supposed to use DoEvents if not in a Do...Loop cycle (that's what microsoft's KB suggests)? Second, how does OnTime relate to my problem? I tried trapping the execution of my macro within a Now - Now+1 timeframe so that if the routine doesn't have "control" (i.e. another macro was fired) it simply aborts. But that doesn't work (I think because the "other macro" I fire, is again a script that has a DoEvent inside).

Comment: Well, you say you want to delay execution of your macro for 1 second... This is what `OnTime` can do. All right... I'll spell it out for you. See my answer in a minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested the following, and it works (assuming I correctly understand what you're trying to do).

In a code module, write this:

```
Public aRunIsScheduled As Boolean
Public nextRunTime As Variant

Sub MyMacro()
    'Flag macro as having been run, no longer scheduled.
    aRunIsScheduled = False

    'Place your macro code here.
    'I'll just use some dummy code:
    MsgBox "MyMacro is running!"

End Sub
```

In your sheet module:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If aRunIsScheduled Then
        ' Cancel the previously scheduled run.
        Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=nextRunTime, _
            Procedure:="MyMacro", Schedule:=False
        aRunIsScheduled = False
    End If

    ' Schedule a new run 3 seconds from now:
    nextRunTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=nextRunTime, _
            Procedure:="MyMacro", Schedule:=True
    aRunIsScheduled = True

End Sub
```

I put a Commandbutton in my sheet and here I'm using its change event, but you can put this code in your `TextBox1_Change()` event instead, in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 2):

reference: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SuppressChangeInForms.htm

To suppress events in a form, you can create a variable at the form's module level called "EnableEvents" and set that to False before changing a property that will cause an event to be raised.

```
Public EnableEvents As Boolean
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub Something()
   Me.EnableEvents = False
   ' some code that would cause an event to run
   Me.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Then, all of the controls on form should have a test if that variable as their order of business in any event code. For example,

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    If Me.EnableEvents = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    MsgBox "List Box Change"
End Sub
```

You can declare the EnableEvents as Private if only procedures with that form need to suppress events. However, if you have forms that are programmatically linked together, such UserForm2 adding an item to a ListBox on UserForm1, you should declare the variable as Public and set it for another form with code like the following:

```
UserForm1.EnableEvents = False
'
' change something on UserForm1
'
UserForm1.EnableEvents = True
```

The primary difference between the EnableEvents property and code shown above and the Application.EnableEvents property is that with a UserForm EnableEvents, all control on the form must have code to exit if EnableEvents is True. In other words, all the form's controls must cooperate and respect the setting of EnableEvents.