# Pressing "Enter" key activates button

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to activate a button when pressing enter after typing something in a cell?

I have a search function where you enter your search string in a cell (C9), and the function is activated when pressing a button. But I'd like to have it activated when pressing enter if you have edited a cell.

So i pseudo-code I am thinking:

```
If enterKey Is Activated Then
    If cursor Is in Range("C9") Then
        FindWords(parameter 1, parameter 2...)
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377237/how-can-i-define-enter-keypressed-event-for-a-dynamically-chosen-cell-in-vba-for

Answer (score 0):

Say we want to detect **two** things:

1. cell **C9** gets changed
2. the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key was used for this change

In a *standard module* enter:

```
Public Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer

Public Function WhichKey() As String

    If (GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyTab)) Then
            WhichKey = "Tab"
            Exit Function
    End If
    If (GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyTab)) Then
            WhichKey = "Tab"
            Exit Function
    End If
    If (GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyDown)) Then
            WhichKey = "Down Arrow"
            Exit Function
    End If
    If (GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyUp)) Then
            WhichKey = "Up Arrow"
            Exit Function
    End If
    If (GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyRight)) Then
            WhichKey = "Right Arrow"
            Exit Function
    End If
    If (GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyLeft)) Then
            WhichKey = "Left Arrow"
            Exit Function
    End If
    If (GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyReturn)) Then
            WhichKey = "Enter"
            Exit Function
    End If
    If (GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyRButton)) Then
            WhichKey = "Right Click"
            Exit Function
    End If
    If (GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyLButton)) Then
            WhichKey = "Left Click"
            Exit Function
    End If
End Function
```

and in the *Worksheet code area* enter:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Range("C9"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If WhichKey() <> "Enter" Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Call FindWords()
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```